# Newbie having trouble with background color

Tags: color, interface-design, background

For the background, I was thinking of a light blue, almost translucent background with tiny white question marks on it. But any attempt just doesn't look right. I can't really place on what is wrong with it and how I should improve. I was wondering if there is a better way to approach making color backgrounds or just backgrounds in general?

Edit: My apologies I should've been more clear. I have looked at color selection and color psychology. I just meant more, I think there is something lacking with my blending and implementation rather than the actual selection of the color.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://paletton.com/#uid=10f0u0kKhr0shEjH1-8NElRRJg9) can help you to chose the right colors for your design just make your original color and he will suggest you similar colors.

And this [site](https://coolors.co/) suggest you palettes collections ready to use for your design